# Is there a way to improve git-diff output?

Tags: git, git-diff

I have source text:

```
=head3 POST /throw/rock


Take a rock, throw it. Well done, you.


=head4 Input

=over

=item direction

Compass point or something.

=item speed

In km/h to annoy home counties people who still think in mp/h.

=back


=head4 Output
```

Which was changed by next text:

```
=head3 POST /throw/rock


=for doc-viewer input-from POST /drive/tank


Take a rock, throw it. Well done, you.


=head4 Output
```

The resulting diff is:
[image]

Are there options in git that force it to not break patches. I expect result like so:

```
 =head3 POST /throw/rock
 
 
+=for doc-viewer input-from POST /drive/tank
-Take a rock, throw it. Well done, you.
-
-
-=head4 Input
 
-=over
-
-=item direction
 
-Compass point or something.
-
-=item speed
-
-In km/h to annoy home counties people who still think in mp/h.
-
-=back
+Take a rock, throw it. Well done, you.
 
 
 =head4 Output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--patience` or `--histogram`; they make this particular case even better, because they notice that there is one line that did not change:

```
@@ -1,22 +1,10 @@
 =head3 POST /throw/rock


+=for doc-viewer input-from POST /drive/tank
+
+
 Take a rock, throw it. Well done, you.


-=head4 Input
-
-=over
-
-=item direction
-
-Compass point or something.
-
-=item speed
-
-In km/h to annoy home counties people who still think in mp/h.
-
-=back
-
-
 =head4 Output
```